# Why does CS0136 error keep on popping up?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I keep on receiving this CS0136 error and I'm unsure why?

```
using System;

namespace Lab2_1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Action<string> cw = Console.WriteLine;
            int[] numbers = new int[10];
            int currentIndex = 0;
            
            bool repeat = true;
            do
            {
                cw("Please enter an interger: ");
                string line = Console.ReadLine();
                if (line == "exit")
                {
                    repeat = false;
                }
                else
                {

                    try
                    {
                        int number = int.Parse(line);
                        cw("The number you entered was: " + number);
                        numbers[currentIndex] = number;
                        currentIndex++;

                    }
                    catch (FormatException)
                    {
                        cw("That wasn't a number!");
                    }
                }

            } while (repeat);
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
            {
                while (repeat) ;

                for (int i = 0; i < currentIndex; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(numbers[i]);
                }

                currentIndex++;
            if (currentIndex == numbers.Length)
                {
                    int expandedNumberOfCells = currentIndex + 10;
                }

                int expandedNumberOfCells = currentIndex + 10;
                int[] expandedNumbers = new int[expandedNumberOfCells]; 
           for (int i = 0; i < currentIndex;  i++)
                {
                    expandedNumbers[i] = numbers[i];
                }
            numbers = expandedNumbers;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should look up the error… [Compiler Error CS0136](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0136) … In your case you need to take a closer look at the… `expandedNumberOfCells` … variable which may be causing the compiler complaint.

Comment: May I know whether your issue have been solved or not? if not, please share it in here, we can work together to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

From [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0136) you can see what error CS0136 is.

You could not declare `expandedNumberOfCells` repeatedly, you can slightly modify your code:

```
int expandedNumberOfCells = currentIndex + 10;
int[] expandedNumbers = new int[expandedNumberOfCells];
if (currentIndex == numbers.Length)
  {
     expandedNumberOfCells = currentIndex + 10;
  }
for (int i = 0; i < currentIndex; i++)
  {
     expandedNumbers[i] = numbers[i];
  }
numbers = expandedNumbers;
```